# Continous integration tool for pure C

Tags: c, svn, continuous-integration, cobol

I have a set of projects with pure C and Cobol code, I am looking for a continuous integration tool, but i have never used these kind of tools before. My code is in `svn` and the most important features I am looking for are:

- Object version tracking
- Compile issues reporting with mails

Does anyone has experience using such tools with C  and Cobol code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jenkins for C continuous integration.  Jenkins jobs can run bash scripts, so at a minimum you can have the script be `make`.  If make returns non-zero, the build will fail.  There is additional stuff you can do to like have gcov/lcov reports collected when you have it up and running as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Jenkins a little bit, and it can do all sorts of interesting things, including integration with most version control systems and automatic emails when builds succeed/fail.

It runs as a web-service on anything that can run Java, pretty much.